# angular2 без node.js

Tags: node.js, angular2

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как запустить откомпилированный скрипт без node.js на веб сервере. Разработка ведётся локально с использованием ноды, а на сервере её нету. Возможно ли запустить приложение на сервере не устанавливая ноду?

**UPDATE 10.06.16:**

index.html собрал так:

  
    Angular 2 QuickStart

```
<!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>

<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.umd.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/@angular/core/core.umd.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/@angular/common/common.umd.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/@angular/compiler/compiler.umd.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/platform-browser.umd.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js"></script>


<script src="app/app.component.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.component.spec.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Loading...

ошибки:
file:///G:/test/main.js    Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
app.component.ts:          1Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
app.component.spec.js:     3 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: А кто же будет выполнять приложение?

Comment: А в чем проблема? Скрипты откомпилированы, должны с сервера грузиться как обычные файлы. У вас на самой ноде есть какая-то бэкенд-логика? Если нода запускается только для lite-server'а то не должно быть проблем.

Comment: нет логики нету. Я просто не совсем понимаю как всё это подключить.

Comment: Допустим у меня есть откомпилированные скрипты. Скажем так, как должен выглядеть index.html?

Comment: Скрипты НЕ КОМ ПИ ЛИ РУ Ю ТСЯ! https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80

Comment: Да, вы правы, я знаю

Comment: @RiĥardBrugekĥaim в angular2 чаще всего используется typescript и он как раз компилируется в javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно просто положить index.html и все зависимые скрипты в рабочую директорию веб-сервера любым удобным способом (ftp, git, ssh, ..). Веб-сервер должен быть настроен на отдачу статики. Нужно быть внимательным с путями в index.html. В принципе это всё.

Comment: тоесть надо просто подключить все библиотеки и js которые собрала нода? system.config.js надо подключать?

Comment: Да, грубо говоря index.html и все, что в него включается. Я не знаю специфики твоей сборки и не в курсе про system.config.js, я дал общий ответ. Если ты что-то пропустишь, это будет видно по 404 ошибкам. Читай и исправляй :). Рекомендую настроить веб-сервер локально и потренироваться, чтобы понять, как он работает. Если есть гарантировано настроенный сервер, тренируйся на нем. Для веб сервера для ангулярного приложения нужны некоторые специфичные настройки. Какие файлы получаются после сборки? Все их обычно и публикуют.