# Как правильно пользоваться node.js

Tags: node.js, angular2

Во-первых, я перерыл миллиард сайтов, но так и не нашел ответа на вопрос: зачем он нужен? Почему нельзя делать все на локальном сервере типа openServer. Во-вторых, допустим, я сделал на node то что нужно было, а как теперь сделать так что бы это все работало на реальном сервере? Захотелось изучить Angular 2, но столкнулся с тем, что для этого нужно использовать node, собственно поэтому такие вопросы...

Answer (score 1):

Вся суть Node.js кроется в определении:

> Node.js (или просто Node) — это серверная платформа для работы с
>   JavaScript через движок V8. JavaScript выполняет действие на стороне
>   клиента, а Node — на сервере. С помощью Node можно писать полноценные
>   приложения. Node умеет работать с внешними библиотеками, вызывать
>   команды из кода на JavaScript и выполнять роль веб-сервера.

Если для ваших требований использование серверного JS ненужно - не используйте, вас никто не заставляет. Однако и требовательным специалистом вы не будете, так как не знаете мейнстримной технологии.

Comment: _"Если для ваших требований использование серверного JS ненужно",_ то очень интересно, как ещё скомпилировать Angular2 ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/533487/angular2-без-node-js

Comment: @Qwertiy, JS не компилируется - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Компилятор

Comment: А ничего, что там не js, а typescript?

Comment: Первое предложение вопроса по ссылке: _"Подскажите, пожалуйста, как запустить **откомпилированный скрипт** без node.js на веб сервере."_ На А2 без тайпскрипта никто не пишет.

Comment: @Qwertiy ES 2017

Comment: Декораторов нет.